# Lower Menu shortcuts disappeared

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, home-screen, samsung-galaxy-sl, dock

I use a Samsung Galaxy SL I9003 model phone with latest version of Gingerbread on it.

I recently started to experience this problem. The shortcut menus on the lower bar have some how disappeared.

Here is a screenshot of the same...

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image to enlarge)</sup>

As of now only the Application shortcut remains.. How do I get the remaining shortcut bak ?

Thanks

P.S : Reboot does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Click that Applications button. Then, long-press and drag whatever icons you want from the list of apps to the drawer. You could drag: People, Phone, a browser, and something else.

Comment: how to drag to the drawer ? Here if I long-press I get the home screen and a remove option in the lower half of the screen.

Comment: @Yasser How about if you go to the applications list? Then, you go to the menu, and click Edit. (I'll update my answer later, if this is the correct procedure)

Comment: @Yasser Or in the home screen, open the menu, and click edit.

Comment: No, unfortunately couldnt find any option where I could drag items to my drawer

Comment: That might depend on the launcher used, but have you tried to drag and drop an app from the drawer to the "launcher bar" directly? Not all launchers support this, but it's worth a try. You could also first create that app icon on the regular home screen, and then try to drag-and-drop it from there.